# Simple perl multithreading for Alien::SeleniumRC

Tags: multithreading, perl, testing, selenium-webdriver, alien

[Alien::SeleniumRC](https://metacpan.org/module/Alien%3a%3aSeleniumRC) says about its `start` method that "This call will block until the server is killed."

I'd like to use it to start the Selenium server, run some Selenium tests, then shut down the Selenium server--all from a single `perl` script.  What's the simplest clean way of achieving this?  (By clean I mean that if something goes wrong, it will shut down the Selenium server on the way out so it doesn't need to be shut down manually.)

Comment: This is on win32 perl 5.10.1 BTW.